# how can I use "fewer" and "more" with numbers?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, phrase-requests, sentence

I have never heard anyone use words "fewer" and "more" when talking about the fact that a certain number of items is greater than a certain number of other items by a constant.

For example if the number of pens that I have is greater than the number of pencils by 5 what is the proper way to say it without using the word "number". Is it "I have 5 more pens than pencils." And "I have 5 fewer pencils than pens." Both of these sentences sound extremely weird and I doubt they are correct, so, what is the proper way of saying these 2 sentences?

Comment: Weirdness aside, they are, in fact, correct.

Comment: Less weird (at least to me): “I have five pens more than (I do) pencils”. Still not quite free of weirdness, but better.

Comment: The pedants will tell you that *"I have 5 **less** pencils than pens"* is invalid/ungrammatical. But I'd rather say that than use ***fewer*** there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both sentences are grammatically correct.

> "I have 5 more pens than pencils."
>
> "I have 5 fewer pencils than pens."

For the record, they *sound* fine to me as well as a native English speaker who regularly has to compare numbers and quantities.

[Oxford dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/translate/english-french/fewer?searchDictCode=all) includes "fewer than 50 people" in an example of word usage.

Comment: "50 fewer" and "fewer than 50" are different examples though.